# mule service start script raises exception with log file

Tags: service, mule, rhel

I'm trying to rewrite the mule start script so it works as a service on a RHEL.

Currently I have it mostly done. 
It is starting and I have the most of the log files being successfully written where I want them. 
But there's a file named literally `.log` that I do not know what is for, neither where to configure (its name and path).

Such file is adding the following nasty lines in the `mule_ee.log` upon start up:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: .log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.openAppend(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:207)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:131)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)
    at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)
    at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:809)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:735)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:615)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:502)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:547)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.log4j.ApplicationAwareRepositorySelector.configureFrom(ApplicationAwareRepositorySelector.java:166)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.log4j.ApplicationAwareRepositorySelector.getLoggerRepository(ApplicationAwareRepositorySelector.java:95)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLoggerRepository(LogManager.java:208)
    at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:228)
    at org.mule.module.logging.MuleLoggerFactory.getLogger(MuleLoggerFactory.java:77)
    at org.mule.module.logging.DispatchingLogger.getLogger(DispatchingLogger.java:419)
    at org.mule.module.logging.DispatchingLogger.isInfoEnabled(DispatchingLogger.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLog.isInfoEnabled(SLF4JLog.java:78)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:188)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.PriviledgedMuleApplication.init(PriviledgedMuleApplication.java:46)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:64)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:46)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService.guardedDeploy(DeploymentService.java:398)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService.start(DeploymentService.java:181)
    at org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.mule.module.reboot.MuleContainerWrapper.start(MuleContainerWrapper.java:56)
    at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager$12.run(WrapperManager.java:3925)`
```

What is that `.log` file for? Where is the conf file to set it up to be written in a place where the mule user has permissions to write?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.log` file seems to be from the **00_mmc-agent** app.

The problem therefore was in the `log4j.properties` file located in `./apps/00_mmc-agent/classes` such file has the following appender configured: `log4j.appender.file.File=${app.name}.log` 
That `${app.name}` variable seem to be not properly configured (not even in the default not modified mule starting script). hence the `.log` file name.

In `./apps/mmc/webapps/mmc/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties` the appender is configured like this `log4j.appender.R.File=${mule.home}/logs/mmc-console-app.log`

So, to fix the startup error I modified the appender of the `log4j.properties` file located in `./apps/00_mmc-agent/classes` to have this path:

`log4j.appender.file.File=${mule.home}/logs/00_mmc-agent.log`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that log4j can't find that file because OS permissions. You can chmod to add permissions in your MULE_HOME dir. And also review your log4j config to see why is trying to read .log file.

Comment: Permissions on MULE_HOME are ok, therefore I can read the rest of log files. I do not know what information comes in that file with that non descriptive name (`.log`), neither where is it configured. Already checked the `log4j.propierties` config files. Nothing found there.

Comment: Actually, you were kind of right, the `log4j.properties` for the `00_mmc-agent` comes with a log file configured that doesn't follow the patterns of the other log4j in the other mule apps. Thank you!